# Автозапуск программы

Tags: c++builder

Добавил программу в автозапуск следующим образом:

```
TRegistry *reg = new TRegistry();
reg->RootKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
reg->OpenKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",true);
reg->WriteString("Test", Application->ExeName);
reg->CloseKey();
reg->Free();
```

Перезагружал комп, а программа за запускается, хотя в автозапуск добавилась
Что у меня не правильно?

Comment: "хотя в автозапуск добавилась" - чем где и как смотрели? АВ установлен?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я через диспетчер задач проверил (у меня Windows 10), и в реестре посмотрел. Что такое AB?

Comment: А у вас Application->ExeName чему именно равно в момент записи в реестр, кстати?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов это путь к екзешнику программы